# Using React useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-context

So i have started using useContext and having trouble resolving a task with it.
I have a state outside my provider function but i dont want to use prop drilling even first level for my button component. I tried to import it from provider function but failed because it is outside this function. Any solutions ?

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import { PostProvider, PostContext } from "./PostContext";

function createRandomPost() {
  return {
    title: `${faker.hacker.adjective()} ${faker.hacker.noun()}`,
    body: faker.hacker.phrase(),
  };
}

function App() {
  const [isFakeDark, setIsFakeDark] = useState(false);

  // Whenever `isFakeDark` changes, we toggle the `fake-dark-mode` class on the HTML element (see in "Elements" dev tool).
  useEffect(
    function () {
      document.documentElement.classList.toggle("fake-dark-mode");
    },
    [isFakeDark]
  );
  // PROBLEM HERE I WANNA HAVE <Button /> without props 
  return (
    // 2) Provide value to child components
    <PostProvider>
      <section>
        <Button setIsFakeDark={setIsFakeDark} isFakeDark={isFakeDark} />

        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Archive />
        <Footer />
      </section>
    </PostProvider>
  );
}

function Button({ setIsFakeDark, isFakeDark }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setIsFakeDark((isFakeDark) => !isFakeDark)}
      className="btn-fake-dark-mode"
    >
      {isFakeDark ? "☀️" : ""}
    </button>
  );
}

function Header() {
  // 3) Consuming context value
  const { onClearPosts } = useContext(PostContext);

  return (
    <header>
      <h1>
        <span>⚛️</span>The Atomic Blog
      </h1>
      <div>
        <Results />
        <SearchPosts />
        <button onClick={onClearPosts}>Clear posts</button>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

function SearchPosts() {
  const { searchQuery, setSearchQuery } = useContext(PostContext);
  return (
    <input
      value={searchQuery}
      onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
      placeholder="Search posts..."
    />
  );
}

function Results() {
  const { posts } = useContext(PostContext);
  return <p> {posts.length} atomic posts found</p>;
}

function Main() {
  return (
    <main>
      <FormAddPost />
      <Posts />
    </main>
  );
}

function Posts() {
  return (
    <section>
      <List />
    </section>
  );
}

function FormAddPost() {
  const { onAddPost } = useContext(PostContext);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!body || !title) return;
    onAddPost({ title, body });
    setTitle("");
    setBody("");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Post title"
      />
      <textarea
        value={body}
        onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Post body"
      />
      <button>Add post</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function List() {
  const { posts } = useContext(PostContext);
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          <h3>{post.title}</h3>
          <p>{post.body}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function Archive() {
  const { onAddPost } = useContext(PostContext);
  // Here we don't need the setter function. We're only using state to store these posts because the callback function passed into useState (which generates the posts) is only called once, on the initial render. So we use this trick as an optimization technique, because if we just used a regular variable, these posts would be re-created on every render. We could also move the posts outside the components, but I wanted to show you this trick 
  const [posts] = useState(() =>
    //  WARNING: This might make your computer slow! Try a smaller `length` first
    Array.from({ length: 100 }, () => createRandomPost())
  );

  const [showArchive, setShowArchive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <aside>
      <h2>Post archive</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setShowArchive((s) => !s)}>
        {showArchive ? "Hide archive posts" : "Show archive posts"}
      </button>

      {showArchive && (
        <ul>
          {posts.map((post, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <p>
                <strong>{post.title}:</strong> {post.body}
              </p>
              <button onClick={() => onAddPost(post)}>Add as new post</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </aside>
  );
}

function Footer() {
  return <footer>&copy; by The Atomic Blog ✌️</footer>;
}

export default App;
```

Second FILE

```
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

function createRandomPost() {
  return {
    title: `${faker.hacker.adjective()} ${faker.hacker.noun()}`,
    body: faker.hacker.phrase(),
  };
}

// 1) Create new Context
const PostContext = createContext();

function PostProvider({ children }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(() =>
    Array.from({ length: 30 }, () => createRandomPost())
  );

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [isFakeDark, setIsFakeDark] = useState(false);
  // Derived state. These are the posts that will actually be displayed
  const searchedPosts =
    searchQuery.length > 0
      ? posts.filter((post) =>
          `${post.title} ${post.body}`
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
        )
      : posts;

  function handleAddPost(post) {
    setPosts((posts) => [post, ...posts]);
  }

  function handleClearPosts() {
    setPosts([]);
  }

  return (
    <PostContext.Provider
      value={{
        posts: searchedPosts,
        onAddPost: handleAddPost,
        onClearPosts: handleClearPosts,
        searchQuery,
        setSearchQuery,
        setIsFakeDark,
        isFakeDark,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </PostContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { PostProvider, PostContext };
```

Comment: regarding your `useState` "trick", you can just use `useMemo` instead. that's what it's for.

Comment: It was pretty easy and dumb i just moved useEffect to Provider file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just moved useEffect to Provider file :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this is about the values `setIsFakeDark` and `isFakeDark` and you want to avoid passing them as props to `PostProvider`.

I would put the theme in its own "`ThemeContext`", and leave the `PostContext` for providing and managing posts only.

```
const themeContext = createContext()
const useTheme = () => {
  const value = useContext(themeContext)
  if (!value) throw new Error('useTheme may only be used in children of a ThemeProvider')
  return value
}
const ThemeProvider = props => {
  const [isFakeDark, setIsFakeDark] = useState(false)
  useEffect(
    () => document.body.classList.toggle("fake-dark-mode", isFakeDark),
    [isFakeDark]
  )
  return (
    <themeContext.Provider value={{ isFakeDark }}>
      {props.children}
    </themeContext.Provider>
  )
}

function App() {
  ...
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <PostProvider>
        ...
      </PostProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```